# How to check if 3 or more variable contains same value in tcl

Tags: tcl

I wanted to know a good way to check if the variable values are same across three or more of the variables in tcl.

```
Suppose $a=abc
    $b=abc
    $c=abc

if ($a,$b,$c value is same)
    puts"write something"

else 
    puts "not same"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `tcl::mathop::eq` (or `tcl::mathop::==` for numeric comparison) command can do exactly that:

```
if {[tcl::mathop::eq $a $b $c]} {
    puts "all equal"
} else {
    puts "at least one is different"
}
```

Comment: It does for me (just tested in 8.5.9, but it's an 8.5 feature in general). Did you try it?

Comment: I just had a run. What if one of the variables has empty or null value. This will consider the condition as false. Any other way we can get around this situation. Should i check if variables contain some values But it would be a length process.Will make code lengthier.

Comment: I included one check statement on the variables like below.

if {$a ne "" && $b ne "" && $c ne "" } {

 puts "then enter"
}

Comment: No nulls in Tcl. Empty strings are simply not equal to other, non-empty strings.

Comment: Any other way i can avoid checking the if condition if one of the values in empty.

Comment: Should I use string length $variable > 0 as a condition to check for null or empty values?

Comment: Does this help: `tcl::mathop::eq {*}[concat [list $a $b $c]]`? This way, empty strings will be omitted from the check (held by whatever variable).

Comment: @mrcalvin but this would return a flattened list after using concat on it.If there was an empty value associated with a variable this would still incorporate in concat and then use mathop to check on the item list. So check still happens if one or two variable values are empty.

Comment: @mrcalvin I am trying to avoid the condition check if we have an empty value associated with any of the variables.

Comment: @donalfellows any other way, we can avoid checking the if condition if one of the values is empty. A solution is to check for the string length of each variable if they are greater than 0. But this would be required for each of the variables.